# Mount data volume to docker with read&write permission

Tags: linux, filesystems, docker

I want to mount a host data volume to docker. But the container should have read and write permission to it, meantime, **any changes on the data volumes should not affect the data in host.**

I can image a solution that mount several data volumes to single folder, one is read only another is read and write. But only this second '-v' works in my command,

```
docker run -ti --name build_cent1 -v /codebase/:/code:ro -v /temp:/code:rw centos6:1.0 bash
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got one answer from nixun in [github](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12867).

> you can simply use overlayfs to fix this:

```
mount -t overlay overlay \
    -olowerdir=/codebase,upperdir=/temp,workdir=/workdir /codebase_new
docker run -ti --name build_cent1 -v /codebase_new:/code:rw centos6:1.0 bash
```

This solution has a good flexibility. Create image with share folder would be a solution, but it cannot update folder data easily.

Answer (score 4):

> only this second '`-v`' works in my command,

That might be because both `-v` options attempt to mount host folders on the *same* container destination folder `/code`.

```
   -v /codebase/:/code:ro 
                 ^^^^^
   -v /temp:/code:rw
            ^^^^^
```

You could mount those host folders in two separate folders within `/code`.
As in:

```
-v /codebase/:/code/base:ro -v /temp:/code/temp:rw.
```

Comment: Yes, what I want is to read and write data in the single container path. But do not corrupt data in host folder.

Comment: @Xiaokun my point is: you cannot mount two different folders to the same destination folder: only the last directive would work. Could you mount them in two separate folders within `/code`? As in `-v /codebase/:/code/base:ro -v /temp:/code/temp:rw`.

Comment: It would not work. Because I want to isolate data(host folder) in docker container. Need to do manipulations(RW) in this folder and not affect host folder. And cannot put it into one specific folder(I cannot write it directly).

Comment: I know that AUFS can do it. Mount several folder to one folder with different permissions. Then it can make sure some source folder is not corrupted.http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/05/linux-aufs/

Comment: @Xiaokun at least you know why your current command does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Normally in this case I think you `ADD` the folder to the Docker image, so that any container running it will have it in its (writeable) filesystem, but writes will go to a different layer.

You need to write a `Dockerfile` in the folder above the one you wish to use, which should look something like this:

```
FROM my/image
ADD codebase /codebase
```

Then you build the container using `docker build -t some-name <path>`.  These steps could be added to the build scripts of your app (maybe you will find some plugin to help there). Then you can `docker run some-name`.

The downside is that there is one copy to do and the image creation, but should you launch many containers they will share the same copy of the layer in read-only and write their own modifications to independent layers above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you help to explain a little bit about the downside? What's the copy process. The image creations process or start container process?

Comment: Another thing is that this way cannot update share folder content easily. I have to create images consistently.

Comment: The copy step has to happen on image creation, which then becomes and integral part of the build process of your codebase. To propagate a change you have to save files, build image, restart the container.... It is not suitable for testing rapidly but there is nothing better AFAIK, with your current constraints.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not for docker users but it will help anyone who uses `Lima` to manage their containers.

I was stuck trying to solve the issue with `limactl` and `lima nerdctl` . I thought it is worth sharing the fix so that it may help anyone in the community who's using `lima` instead of `docker`:

By default `Lima` mounts volumes as read only. to be make them writeable by default do the following:

Edit the file and set `write: true` under `mount` section

`$ vim  ~/.lima/default/lima.yaml`

then restart lima

```
limactl list #this lists all running vms 
limactl stop default #or name of the machine 
limactl start default #or name of the machine
```

you would still need to specify mount options exactly as with `docker`

```
    lima nerdctl run -ti --name build_cent1 \
    -v /codebase/:/code/base:ro \
    -v /temp:/code/temp:rw \
    centos6:1.0 bash
```

For more information about lima, please check [this](https://github.com/lima-vm/lima) out